# Is $\Phi(\alpha)(t)=-\alpha(t)$ a contraction at the space of parametric curves

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, metric-spaces, fixed-points

We are in the metric space of the continous parametric curves with the uniform metric. Let $\Phi(\alpha)(t)=-\alpha(t)$. Is this a contraction? I don’t know how could I start this problem. Also, does it has a fixed point

Comment: For contraction, note that $\Phi\circ\Phi$ is the identity. On the other hand, the fixed point ($\alpha$ with $\Phi(\alpha)=\alpha$) is quite obvious from the definition ...

Comment: It would be helpful to specify the space of curves and to specify your definition of contraction as your function takes $2$ arguments; it is ambiguous.